# Redux store updating strangely

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having a code that looks like this

reducer

```js
const initState = { isLoggedIn: false };
const isLoggedInReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOG_IN":
      return { isLoggedIn: true };
    case "LOG_OUT":
      return { isLoggedIn: false };
    default:
      return {isLoggedIn:false};
  }
};

export default isLoggedInReducer;
```

action

```js
export const logIn = () => {
    return {
        type:'LOG_IN'
    }
}

export const logOut = () => {
    return {
        type:'LOG_OUT'
    }
}
```

screen

```js
import React from 'react'
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {logIn , logOut} from '../redux/actions/isLoggedInAction'

const AuthScreen = () => {
    console.log('auth page re-rendered')
    let status = useSelector(state => state.isLoggedIn)
    console.log(status)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    return <>
        <h1> auth is {status} status</h1>
        <button onClick={()=>dispatch(logIn())}>authenticate me</button>
        <button onClick={()=>dispatch(logOut())}>un auth me</button>
    </>
}

export default AuthScreen
```

The problem is, something causes the app to render twice, and update the store
[image]

The variable should not have changed unless I dispatch an action, which I clearly did not. Also the value of the variable is logged out but doesnt print inside the h1 tag.

If I change the default case of the reducer to something like

```js
const initState = { isLoggedIn: false };
const isLoggedInReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOG_IN":
      return { isLoggedIn: true };
    case "LOG_OUT":
      return { isLoggedIn: false };
    default:
      return {isLoggedIn:' hello world'};
  }
};

export default isLoggedInReducer;
```

Then I get this output

[image]

The above output suggests that the default case was somehow run. But again, I did not dispatch any action to it. I am only reading the data using the "useSelect" but something is dispatching actions that I dont know about.

I am very new to redux and trying to learn. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your default case is strange. Why do you always return a new object? Any action (would be considered a mutation. Should be  `default: return state;`

Comment: may be a bit much to ask, but could you maybe provide a live demo of your code so that it can be checked out? like by using https://codesandbox.io/ or something

Because at a first glance I can't see the problem but by playing around with it a bit I could try to help out :)

Comment: Could be init action is called (check redux devtools) or maybe your reducer is called by combineReducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your default case, return the state as is:

```
default:
    return state;
```

If you return a new object, React will treat the state as having changed and rerender the component, as equality is checked by ref by default.

Comment: even if I change my default case to the above mentioned, the mysterious action calls still exist

Comment: @LakshayDutta What is the type of the action, you can log the action.type?

Comment: I dont know how, but mysteriously the unknown calls dissapeared. I dont understand why, but thank you for the answer!